# pyqt5 edit taskbar under windows 10

Tags: pyqt5, taskbar

Do someone have an example code how to manipulate the taskbar under windows 10? Like adding buttons or a taskbar progress.

Something like (self is the mainwindow)

```
    self.task_button = QWinTaskbarButton(self)
    self.task_progress = self.task_button.progress()
    self.task_progress.setMinimum(0)
    self.task_progress.setMaximum(100)
    self.task_progress.setValue(50)
    self.task_progress.resume()
    self.task_progress.show()
    self.task_progress.setVisible(True)
```

Did not worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I couldn't easily find an answer, so for the record, this is what I had to do

Assume, this is in a class, inheriting from `QMainWindow`

```py
from PyQt5.QtWinExtras import QWinTaskbarProgress, QWinTaskbarButton

...

    def showEvent(self, evt):
        self.taskbar_button = QWinTaskbarButton()
        self.taskbar_progress = self.taskbar_button.progress()
        self.taskbar_progress.setRange(0, 100)
        self.taskbar_progress.show()
        self.taskbar_button.setWindow(self.windowHandle())
```

From then on, in your application, you can manipulate the self.taskbar_progress property. Here are a few examples for reference

```py
# Set value
self.taskbar_progress.setValue(55)

# Pause state (yellow bar)
self.taskbar_progress.pause()
# Or
self.taskbar_progress.setPaused(True)

# Stop (red bar)
self.taskbar_progress.stop()

# Run again (green bar)
self.taskbar_progress.resume()
```

For further reference, see the [c++ reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwintaskbarprogress.html) (python versions match those)